# Has Kaido eaten a devil fruit? If so, what is its power?

Tags: one-piece

Kaido is called the strongest creature in the One Piece world. Hence, he must be immensely powerful.

My question is: What is his power? Is he a devil fruit user?

Comment: If i were to guess i'd say he has a devil fruit. To be honest, its hard to believe that a normal person could survive falling a 1000 feet without dying. But then again, he might just have crazy luck lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We still don´t know if Kaidou is a devil fruit user or if he as any kind of power but [his Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kaido) page says the following:

> Perhaps the greatest sign of Kaido's strength is his inability to die. He has been caught and tortured 18 times, and people have attempted to execute him 40 times. However, he mysteriously survived every single attempt because every single execution weapon has broken when being used on him. Kaido also managed to singlehandedly sink nine huge prison ships. Most notably, Kaido has jumped from 10,000 meters in the sky onto the ground, creating a massive shockwave strong enough to sink a large ship nearby, and emerged without a single injury. It has even become a hobby for him to attempt suicide only for it to fail.

Answer (score 7):

**SPOILERS AHEAD**

It has been confirmed in Chapter 921 of *One Piece*, that Kaido has a Zoan Devil Fruit ability (mostly Mythical). His Devil Fruit lets him change into a huge

> Dragon

Reference:

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that we currently don't know.

However, Kaidou is often referred to as the "strongest creature in the world" (Chapter 697, page 4), insinuating that he might not be human. This might refer to a special devil fruit that he has eaten (devil fruit eaters have previously been referred to as "monsters"), or just to the fact that he has horns.

Another possibility is that he is so strong, so powerful and so impossible to kill (as he's been tortured, captured and even tried to kill himself by jumping from 10,000 meters to the ground) that people just call him a "monster", as they did for Whitebeard.

Answer (score 5):

The Devil Fruit's name is not yet stated, but based on his appearance and power, probably a Dragon Devil Fruit (Ryu-Ryu no mi?). Most likely a mythical Zoan since he has a fiery aura reminiscent of Marco's phoenix form. It also explains how he managed to burn down Owen castle single-handedly and why he has horns, and the dragon scale tattoo.

Answer (score 4):

I just realize something from this statement From *One Piece Wikia*, here:

> Perhaps the greatest sign of Kaido's strength is his apparent inability to die. He has been caught and tortured 18 times, and people as powerful as the Marines and other Yonko have attempted to execute him 40 times. However, he mysteriously survived every single attempt because every single execution weapon broke when being used on him. Most notably, Kaido has jumped from 10,000 meters in the sky onto the ground, creating a massive shockwave strong enough to sink a large ship nearby, and emerged without an injury; it has even become a hobby for him to attempt suicide, only for it to fail.

If he had any Devil Fruit power, then it should be easy to commit suicide, just drown yourself in to the bottom of the ocean.

So the answer is no, he just super strong like Shanks.

Comment: +1. I also noticed that another way to kill himself is to eat another devil fruit if he's already a user.